# Views slideshow overlapping right hand sidebar block

Tags: blocks, javascript

I'm using the default bartik theme and have created a views slideshow.  I have a url for this and have marked this as the front page under the admin section.  All great so far, in that when the (unauthenticated) user first visits the site they see the slideshow.  Once they log in, I have a block that appears in the right hand side sidebar.  However, the width of my slideshow is too wide in that it appears overlapped with this block on the right.  What is the best way to address this?  I could fix the width of the slideshow, but then that means I loose the flexibility to easily change the theme.

Also, can anyone point me to documentation that would help me understand why this happens?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Sorry, this is Drupal 7.

Comment: Might be worth studying the CSS positioning attributes and seeing what can be adjusted there, there may be a rule that allows for this overlap that you don't want, and so it may be possible to switch it off.

Comment: What is the block that appears on the right?

Comment: It's a block containing a view of the last 5 items of a custom node.

Comment: I think I may know what the issue is, but I would be making assumptions. Can you provide a link/screenshot to the site?

Answer (score 1):

I found two ways of resolving this.

1. Permissioning the splash screen so that only non authenticated users can see it.  That way, whenever anyone logs in they do not see the slideshow.
2. Use the corporate clean them - much better than anything I can develop!